# Open sql connection in business service

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlconnection, database-agnostic, tightly-coupled-code

Do you see it as tight coupling that my business service class opens a SqlConnection ?

Actually a business service should not be aware of the concrete dataprovider?!

**public class UnitService:**

```
 public void DeleteUnit(Unit unit)
            {
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection());
                using (TransactionScope trans = new TransactionScope())
                {
                    con.Open();

                    _unitDataProvider.Delete(unit,con);
                    _employeeDataProvider.UpdateEmployees(con);

                    trans.Complete();
                }             
            }
```

Comment: What's the point of opening the `con` if it is another object, `unitDataProvider`, responsible for actual deletion and the connection doesn't seem to be passed down to this another object?

Comment: ah sorry its pseoudo code, of course both dataprovider methods accept the connection as parameter to execute their sqlcommands on it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your qustion is very subject to opinion...

I love to abstract code and uncouple everywhere possible.  The question, as always, is that of time and requirements.

For a small simple project that does not require extensive Unit Testing within the Business Tier, your coupling although does not necessarily follow *best practice* may be exactly what the customer/end-user requires, and may allow you to provide the software in a more timely fashion.

For a larger/more complex/etc project it may be best to abstract the persistance layer.

It is simply not feasible to follow *best practices*, *best design patterns*, and *best coding principles* for *every line of code* you write.  I've found the authors of [such books](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Principles-Patterns-Practices-Robert-Martin/dp/0131857258/ref=pd_sim_b_29) quite often mention the patterns as potentially surplus to requirements and should simply be used as a tool, when needed.

Hope that helps?

Answer (score 0):

> Do you see it as tight coupling that my business service class opens a
>   SqlConnection ?

Yes. If you have some calculation to do that job you can do in Business layer before reaching to presentation layer.

One more thing I would like to suggest is to use "Using" statements for the IDisposable Objects in case of `SQLConnection class`

I meant It should be like below.

```
using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("YourConnection string")) {
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    string expression = "Parameter value";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "Your Stored Procedure";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Your Parameter Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = expression;
    cmd.Connection = con;
    using (IDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
        if (dr.Read()) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ah darn pseudo code :P I used a using for the connection stuff too in my real code just see the using trans...